# Comparing Names in array to themselves

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, data-structures

I have an Array of names I sorted alphabetically. Many names repeat themselves and I track each occurrence as Popularity  I have been trying to figure out how I can compare each Index and the one next to it to see if its the same name or not. Each time the same name appears I have a counter that ticks up, when it reaches a different name it checks its occurrence vs "foundNamePop" it stores the counter in a separate variable and resets. The problem is that some Arrays as input have the same name repeating at the end of the array (i.e. Lane, Lane, Lane \0) it leaves out of my IF LOOP and doesn't store it because I just have only the "nameCounter++". I just can't seem to find the solution to making sure it reads every name and store it all no matter if there are multiple names at the end or single names that are different i.e.(Lane, Dane, Bane \0).

Let me also add these .txt files can contain ~50 thousand names and I have no idea what names are in there.

Why does that ending If statement not work it just enters like normal. I ran with debugging and i watched it just slip right into the function even when .ElementsAt(i).Value > (5 for this instance)

```
        var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (var name in updatedName)
        {
            dict.AddOrUpdate(name, 1, (_, count) => ++count);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
         {
            if (dict.ElementsAt(i).Value <= foundNamePop);
            {
                lessPopNameSum += dict.ElementAt(i).Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just GroupBy name and look at the count of each group?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to add a check after the loop

```
if (foundNamePop >= nameCounter)
{
      lessPopNameSum += nameCounter;
}
```

But it is not clear to me what you are actually computing, it looks like you are summing the duplicate names that have more duplicates than `foundNamePop`, but it is not clear what value this has, nor what actual meaning the result will have.

You should be able to use LINQ to get something similar with less code:

```
var lessPopNameSum = sameLengthName
    .GroupBy(n => n)
    .Select(group => group.Count())
    .Where(c => c >= foundNamePop)
    .Sum();
```

Comment: I will try both of these. The purpose of this is to calculate the Misspellablity of a given name. That name is then searched through a .txt document with ~50 Thousand lines containing names. I then have to sort the list alphabetically and rid the names with an edit distance more then one. I used Levenshtein distance for this. Now that I have a cleaned up array of names I need to compare this organized array to each name in the Array and calculate how many times the name appears. Which is what I am trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Wynn Berry I'm not sure your algorithm does what you intend. Consider the strings `aa, ab, za`. What string should remain? all have an edit distance of one to the first string.

Comment: I already coded the Levenshtein Distance already, and used its output to generate an Array based on the constraints of edit distance 1. This is the last step in my code, I need to tally up all the names and their occurrences in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the elegance of the other posted solution another alternative could be to use a `Dictionary` to store a `count` of each of the names.

```
const int FoundNamePop = 2;

var names = new string[] { "Bill", "Jane", "Jeff", "Rebecca", "Bill" };
var count = FindPopularNames(names)
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value < FoundNamePop)
    .Sum(kvp => kvp.Value);

// With 'FoundNamePop' set to two, the below line will print '3'.
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {count}");

static IDictionary<string, int> FindPopularNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>
        (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        dict.AddOrUpdate(name, 1, (_, count) => ++count);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: I like this REALLY LIKE, but how do I access the number, compare it to the foundNamePop=(for the sake of argument we can say 5) if the dict number stored is less than 5 we add the dict value to a counter "lessPopNameSum" because now I need that total sum of all the names with less occurrence to be added together so I can preform Math with it.

Comment: Are you looking for all `names` that have a `count` greater than `foundNamePop`?

Comment: Less than ^^ I edited the above comment

Comment: So I showed how you can calculate the desired value. I set `FoundNamePop` to `2` so you can see how the `count` associated with `Bill` is ignored due to his `count` being equal to `2`. You could alter the `FindPopularNames` to return this count value instead of the dictionary if you wanted.

Comment: I updated the main code above, now I tried to do a conditional statement to see each Value stored in the dict, but it falls right through! WHat am I doing wrong now!